# Send push notification with Parse and a webservices with django

Tags: django, parse-platform, push-notification, django-rest-framework

Is there some way to send push notifications using Parse and a web service built in Django? I mean, I have a dashboard built in django, in this dashboard I can set it up some parameters, when I create for example a new news, this has to be notified to the user through a push notifications. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

See that page... https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide you should try make a request similar to this....every time you make some news

```
    import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/classes/GameScore', json.dumps({
       "score": 1337,
       "playerName": "Sean Plott",
       "cheatMode": False
     }), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
results = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print results
```